# How to match or search a documents which is stored in mongodb as base64 encrypted?

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate

I have data as given below

```
{
  "_id": "d-0054d4df-8d94-48c5-be1d-cf5204c1f1a9",
  "mobileVerified": false,
  "emailVerified": false,
  "onBoardingStatus": "TRUE",
  "isActive": true,
  "email": "0baf3defd5a8eccba00f5e0db4ecd047.78e84af3e1f98d7a4b55b8b5f6a27f471fc882098d80a052a62910bdf179bd47",
  "mobile": "95885ce3422f8c43d5120b81afe1bc15.ff266a58bc9a719697663294f4d233f1",
  "password": "$2b$08$RM01UrzlKQetPTFuGVjg5.wE264irNxA4tdHg48tXwFGLE8kjQHee",
  "userType": "STUDENT",
  "isPublic": true
}
```

Now I need to run a match or search pipeline on these types of document and the keys are email and mobile. But here mobile and email is the encrypted format. Is there any way to implement a search(regex) or match pipeline on these data.

Comment: two remarks: 1. base64 is just encoding and not encryption, but often encrypted information is also additionally base64 encoded  2. email and mobile might be encrypted here, but they're not stored in base64 format but hex encoded.

Comment: yes, I got your point but how can I query data on the encoded field.

Answer (score 0):

In your application, encode the value you are searching for using the same encoding used for the stored data.

Then search by the encoded value.

Comment: Here I am talking about encoding. Let's example user type something XYZ then the encoded value of XYZ is totally different.

Comment: Right. Encode the user's input in your application.